ProviderIncompatibleException with Npgsql, Postgresql 16.1 and .NET Framework 4.8
I have a legacy Entity Framework application running on .NET Framework 4.8.
Until recently, it connected well to Postgresql 11. Now we upgraded Postgresql to 16. We also upgraded the packages Npgsql, EntityFramework6.Npgsql, and EntityFramework. Now we get this error:

System.Data.Entity.Core.ProviderIncompatibleException: 'An error
occurred accessing the database. This usually means that the
connection to the database failed. Check that the connection string is
correct and that the appropriate DbContext constructor is being used
to specify it or find it in the application's config file. See
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=386386 for information on
DbContext and connections. See the inner exception for details of the
failure.'

The inner exception is:
System.Data.Entity.Core.ProviderIncompatibleException
"The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string."

The inner exception of that is:
"Method not found: 'System.String Npgsql.NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder.get_EntityAdminDatabase()'."
System.MissingMethodException

How can we fix this?

I recently faced the same issue.
My guess is that you are also using Npgsql >= v8.0.0 and EntityFramework6.Npgsql ~ v6.4.3. The problem is that NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder.EntityAdminDatabase property was dropped in Npgsql since v8, but there is (probably) no version of EntityFramework6.Npgsql that can do without it.
I tried to create public class MyNpgsqlServices : NpgsqlServices and override all the methods that depend on EntityAdminDatabase, only to find out that there are other parts of Npgsql public api that were dropped in v8 (like NpgsqlCommand.ObjectResultTypes property), which EntityFramework6.Npgsql still needs.
So for me, the simplest solution right now is to keep using Npgsql < v8, I chose 6.0.11 at the moment.
